# How to make next string to be in next line in jquery

Tags: jquery

I m trying to display data in model window,where SaveFirst,Savesecond,Savethird,Savefourth should come one after the other.Here i am using  tag.

But it appears in same line.

```
$("#prettyWindow").html('<br><xmp>'+SaveFirst+''+Savesecond+''+Savethird+''+Savefourth+'</xmp>');
```

Please help me

Comment: fill the blank between Saves with '<br />'

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#prettyWindow").html('<br><xmp>'+ SaveFirst + '<br />' + Savesecond + '<br />' + Savethird + '<br />' + Savefourth + '</xmp>');
```